# Minecraft command block teleport with Target selector arguments

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a 1 tick clock, which leads to a command block with the command:

```
testfor @p[-262,3,113,1] {SelectedItem:{id:minecraft:stick}}
```

That works. It finds me under the right conditions.

Then I have a redstone comparator, leading to a redstone repeater (seemed to be needed), then another command block for the actual command to do.

If the (second) command is

```
tp @p -268 3 113
```

then it works.

If it is any of the following then it won't teleport (though the first command block is finding me)

```
tp @p[-262,3,113,1] -268 3 113
tp @p[x=-262,y=3,z=113,r=1] -268 3 113
tp @p[-262,3,113,1] {SelectedItem:{id:minecraft:stick}} -268 3 113
tp @p[x=-262,y=3,z=113,r=1] {SelectedItem:{id:minecraft:stick}} -268 3 113
```

Can anyone suggest an answer?

Edit:

I'm on Minecraft 1.8.8.

Here's the clock (off to the right is a switch to turn it on and off, off to the left is the command block circuit).
[image]

Here's the main circuit. The right hand command block is the first (the testfor). Behind it is a redstone repeater.

The left hand command block is the second (the tp).

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Just something to try - have you tried changing the `@p` in the tp command to `@a`?

Comment: I really suggest using execute instead of testfor. Testfor has way too many problems for doing something when something happens without it being singleplayer.

Comment: @angussidney - how would that work? I need the closest people to the point defined, that are carrying a stick. Surely if I use @a then that gives me anyone carrying a stick. Could you clarify?

Comment: @Judge2020 - I'd be interested to see examples. Still, the Testfor seems to fire fine (I've still got the console showing results and it's finding me, it's just the /tp that is not working). Sure, I had to reinforce it with a redstone reinforce which seemed strange, but it seems to work fine.

Comment: I'm reading up on execute; very interesting. I can't yet see how it can be used to take the nearest person to a position, limited to within a given radius, who is holding a particular item, and teleport them to a particular location. That said, while I very much want to know the reason why the original question is so (I think it's a bug or limitation), I would welcome a workaround to achieve my ultimate aim.

Comment: All but the last two commands should work. If it is not working, it is a problem with your setup and we'd need a screenshot of it. I'd also recommend using scoreboards for this, as what you're doing currently will not target the player holding the stick if another player is closer to the point while someone else holds the stick.

Comment: @JamesCarlyle-Clarke It should teleport everyone on *that block*. So if two people walk onto the block you specified, it should teleport them both. This is because the requirements for the block is attached to the selector.

Comment: @angussidney - tried the @a, doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @colorfusion, noted, I'll try the answer below, once I can figure out how to make it go. Thanks, both of you.

Comment: I've added the circuit

Comment: **Stop what you're doing!**  You're mixing redstone dust and command blocks, which is a Bad Idea™!  You should eliminate as much redstone dust as possible.  Redstone dust in a command block contraption is the devil, it is pure evil, you do not want it anywhere near you.  Your first step should be to get rid of it.

Comment: Looking back at the commands you have given, are you **sure** that the `testfor @p[-262,3,113,1] {Inventory:{id:minecraft:stick}}` is finding you under the right conditions? I didn't really look at it at first because you repeated that the testfor part was working fine, but that command is malformed and shouldn't be working. It seems like the second command block shouldn't be activating at all; have you seen the repeater become powered?

Comment: @colorfusion - you are right, turns out when I copied the text of my command I got an older one; 'Inventory' in all the above commands should read 'SelectedItem'. Sorry, I've edited. The core point stands though - it does indeed find me (with that change), and the tp only works on the very limited case given.

Comment: @MBraedley, an interesting point, and certainly something I'll look into once I get the basic case working. I've done some reading and will certainly implement a redstone dust reduction later.

Comment: @MBraedley - or are you saying that the redstone could be the reason the system is not working? Because it seems strange to me that the first two commands work and none of the rest do.

Comment: It's possible.  The fastest that you can reliably clock a redstone line is 5Hz, and even that is too fast for some things.  The bigger problem is the lag that redstone generates.  You probably want to be using a 20Hz clock anyways, and you probably want to ditch the `testfor` command in favour of using a scoreboard, especially if you want this to be multiplayer safe.

Answer (score -1):

Comparator and fast clocks don't mix well so here is a complete clock only solution.

Setup:

```
/scoreboard objectives add Selector dummy
/scoreboard objectives add Marker dummy
/summon ArmorStand -262 3 113 {Silent:1,CustomName:"Tracker",Invulnerable:1,Invisible:1,Marker:1,NoGravity:1}
```

Clock:

```
/scoreboard players set @a Selector 0
/scoreboard players set @a[x=-262,y=3,z=113,r=1] Selector 1 {Inventory:{id:minecraft:stick}}
/scoreboard players set @e Marker 0
/scoreboard players set @e[type=ArmorStand] Marker 1 {Silent:1,CustomName:"Tracker",Invulnerable:1,Invisible:1,Marker:1,NoGravity:1}
/execute @e[type=ArmorStand,score_Marker_min=1] ~ ~ ~ tp @p[r=1] -268 3 113
```

Comment: Additionally, the new snapshots have added a feature allowing command blocks to be set up to repeat and chain without any need for redstone or comparators. May be worth checking out if you aren't particularly tied to 1.8.

Comment: Confused as to what you're trying to do here. You're setting everyone's `Selector` score to 0, then setting everyone holding a stick's `Selector` score to 0 again, then doing absolutely nothing based off of the `Selector` score? ArmorStands don't have an inventory tag, and what is an ArmorStand needed for in OP's question anyway?

Comment: The second selector is my bad, the selector is for the player and the armor stand is to used to find the closest player to the selecting point.

Comment: The inventory i copied the wrong thing. :P

Comment: Thanks @ModDL; presumably the setup should be run once via a command block (or more often? When?), and the clock section should be run from the clock via a command block?  And can I use something other than an ArmorStand? I guess I'll try it and see. I'm trying to see how it would work over the life of a level... Since I have an on/off switch on the clock, would it be worth pairing the setup commands with another set to 'clear up', ie remove the objectives and the armorstand, with the setup being run when I switch it on, and the clear up being run when I switch it off?

Comment: Is there ever a case where the setup might be run multiple times and so I end up with multiple ArmorStands? (perhaps when I start and stop the server, or something, since this is a server-based level) Is there a case for putting the ArmorStand (or a different block, if that works) there myself first rather than doing it by command block, to avoid that?

Comment: @ModDL These commands are still completely broken. The ArmorStand (which is unnecessary in the first place) is going to constantly teleport anyone in a radius of 1 around it to -268, 3, 113, regardless of whether or not they have a stick in their inventory. The answer also doesn't really explain why OP's commands (which should be working) aren't working.